# How is font icon inserted into a webpage?

Tags: fonts, icons, css

I would consider the following HTML element as an empty element and displays no ***content*** in a browser window:

```
<p class="sample_class"></p>
```

But when it comes to adding icons to HTML pages, such as the following sample code for adding Font Awesome icons(From W3CSchools.com):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
<i class="fa fa-file"></i>
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

There are actually font icons/symbols displayed in a browser window. Why?
Isn't every single one of the `<i> </i>` element empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents that you see comes from the CSS. CSS can add contents too, using the `:before` and `:after` designators. If you look at `font-awesome.min.css`, you'll find the following lines, although not in this order:

```
.fa-cloud:before {
    content:"\f0c2"
}
.fa-heart:before {
    content:"\f004"
}
.fa-automobile:before,.fa-car:before {
    content:"\f1b9"
}
.fa-file:before {
    content:"\f15b"
}
.fa-navicon:before,.fa-reorder:before,.fa-bars:before {
    content:"\f0c9"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know CSS was able to do that.